# How can I add a calendar with google calendar api?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-calendar

Helo,

how can I insert a new calendar with google calendar api?

I tried the following code and executed with new Retrievetask().execute():

```
class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(CalendarActivity.this.getFilesDir(), ".credentials/calendar-java-quickstart"));
            List<String> SCOPES =
                    Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);

            JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
                    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            InputStream in =
                    Events.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_id.json");
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                    GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                            .setAccessType("online")
                            .build();
            Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("kalender")
                    .build();


            com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar cal = new com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar();
            cal.setSummary("test123");

            service.calendars().insert(cal);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("test failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But i application crashes with the following error (see bottom post).

When I try without Asynctask, then I get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

What am I doing wrong?

> 08-23 14:17:13.926 16556-16675/de.ubik.kalender E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>                                                                     Process: de.ubik.kalender, PID: 16556
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljava/awt/Desktop;
>                                                                         at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:127)
>                                                                         at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:111)
>                                                                         at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:79)
>                                                                         at
>   de.ubik.kalender.CalendarActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(CalendarActivity.java:199)
>                                                                         at
>   de.ubik.kalender.CalendarActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(CalendarActivity.java:171)
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "java.awt.Desktop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.ubik.kalender-1/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                                                                         at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                         at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:127) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:111) 
>                                                                         at
>   com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:79) 
>                                                                         at
>   de.ubik.kalender.CalendarActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(CalendarActivity.java:199) 
>                                                                         at
>   de.ubik.kalender.CalendarActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(CalendarActivity.java:171) 
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
>                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

What am I doing wrong